# Alternative to pyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

i'm learning something about game programming from a book about "pyGame". pyGame is simple, but... python is a little complex and different from my previous knoweledge about programming.

I know "classical" language: C# (also C/C++), Java ... I know a lot of people love Python but for me is a little harder to learn!

So I'm looking something like "pyGame" but for java or for c# ... A library with which I can do almost the same thing i can do with pygame (so .. do more with less code ... and headache).

Comment: Honestly, I would spend an afternoon with the Python Tutorial (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Python has a few oddities, but it's a fairly simple language to learn.

Comment: You won't find much that lets you do more with less code than Pygame. Pygame's rendering model is simple to the point of stupidity and uselessness on modern computers (CPU-side framebuffers), and the interface is nearly as high-level as you can get for those.

Comment: complex? python? sbrotfl. Dive into Python is one of the best guides I've ever read http://diveintopython.org/toc/index.html

Comment: I learned Python in an afternoon (from years of C++ experience) and within a week I was writing more functionality faster in Pygame.

Comment: On a second look at this question, it is very misleading. The title suggests 'What other libraries are there for python?' but the question is actually 'what 2D APIs are there for java or C#?' which is totally different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Love](http://love2d.org/) offers a similar level of complexity as PyGame, though I'm not sure you will find Lua much easier than Python. If you want to just go with something more direct, look for bindings for SDL ([SDL.NET](http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/index.php) for example) for your favorite language, or even just use it directly in C. Many PyGame APIs are just thin wrappers for SDL functionality.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know SDL.NET . I think it is what i'm looking for;)!

Comment: nitpick: It's LÖVE.

Comment: The LÖVE library is actually easier to start out with than PyGame's because a lot of nice little things like sprite animation are already done for you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with pyGame but if you're looking for a nice easy framework to use for game development why not use XNA 4.0? It's free and lets you create games that can be played on the XBox 360, Zune HD or Windows Phone 7.

The benefit of using this is you can very easily leverage your C# knowledge and start working right away with learning the framework instead of wrestling with the language.

I **highly** suggest you start learning XNA by following this great series of tutorials made by [Riemers](http://riemers.net/).

Comment: Being familiar with both, XNA is nowhere near similar to PyGame. The graphics APIs are far lower level and it doesn't offer anything like the basic sprite system in PyGame.

Comment: Then that settles it; XNA would probably be your best choice OP. It's very simple to use and effective.

Comment: @coderanger: XNA has sprites. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194908.aspx. They are considerably better than Pygame sprites, since they can actually use hardware acceleration. (And thereby good rotation, shaders, etc.)

Comment: @Joe SpriteBatch.Draw is really just an equivalent to PyGame's blit call, not the Sprite class. I don't think I've ever had performance problems with PyGame/SDL, especially if he is just using it to start out.

Comment: I strongly recommend XNA for beginners. I've had a pretty good experience with it.

Comment: I'd point out that XNA's platform support is completely different from PyGame's. It's hardly a replacement if you are targeting any non-MS device.

Comment: XNA is very bound to Microsoft and thus leads to Vendor lock-in. Also PyGame is cross-platform and you can write your games in python, which makes it even simpler.

Comment: If one is concerned about cross platform support, one might consider [ANX Framework](http://anxframework.codeplex.com/). This way you can still use C# and the XNA API.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames has the list of python game engines/libraries. Some of the game engines in the list are not Python only. Ogre and Panda are well known ones in both you can use c++.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+C Ctrl+V from another question I posted on

> [**Slick**](https://slick.ninjacave.com/) is a nice 2D Java
> library based off of LWJGL. It handles
> the game loop, rendering, and contains
> useful functionality to implement
> sprites.
>
> It comes bundled with many different
> demos and examples.

Things like tilemaps, sprite sheets, etc are all built in.  Basically lets you focus on the game, not how to write an engine.

Comment: What does Ctrl+P do?

Comment: Typing mistake =p Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1):

If you know C, I'd recommend Allegro, game programming library. That's what I used when I was getting into game dev, and it served me well back then. It has similar capabilities to SDL, but for me it was always simpler, and more straightforward. They even say on the website that there are bindings for C#, but I have no idea how those work.

http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/

Also, I find it very weird, that you say you know C++ but can't learn Python. Python is way simpler and easier to use than C++.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think anything can do better than pygame:
SDL is simple enough, so it's a good choice.
Python, when thinking about programmer-friendliness, is like the best language ever.
I don't think you can do much better than pygame.

Answer (score 0):

SDL is made with c and is perhaps the most popular game programming library. Also I think I did read somewhere that pyGame is based on it.

http://www.libsdl.org/

Answer (score 0):

- [angel-engine](http://code.google.com/p/angel-engine/) is for simple prototyping but is pretty complete.
- [panda 3d](http://www.panda3d.org/) is a full fledged 3d engine with commercial games using it, but has a relatively simple python interface if you don't want to get fancy (just look at the simplest examples).

Both are well documented.