# Basic developing in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I have basic experience in Python, and I want to know which is the best library to use in development. I was looking originally at Pygame but found it a bit lacking in tutorials. Are there any good ones for Pygame? And if not, is there any nice alternative to the Pygame library, or Python itself?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/alternative-to-pygame

Comment: Oh boy another prime example of research effort and originality fused together into a very constructive game development question! This totally hasn't been answered one billion times already, and definitely doesn't lie just a few queries away from your favorite search engine!

Answer (score 4):

I always found [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) to be a very nice alternative to PyGame. To me it felt more Pythonic and came with an good [programming guide](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/index.html) (next to the API documentation, of course) that almost always helped me get along.

Comment: I have a completely opposite experience: didn't manage to even mirror a sprite with pyglet, trashed it and switched to pygame.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the original [Cocos 2D](http://cocos2d.org/), as well as [Panda 3D](http://www.panda3d.org/).

Haven't done a lot of game programming in Python. I just know that if you want to try anything more than the absolute basics with audio in Python that you should avoid pygame like the plague, or at least find an alternate sound module.

Answer (score 0):

A good tutorial on pygame is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xgn-HKzZes.